# Is it possible to reset a branch to a particular state and cherry pick the later commits done on the same branch?

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, version-control

I have a customebranch->master and made changes in custom branch and now having 5 commits.

Accidently, in first commit I have pushed some .exe file and realised now that this should not be committed.

Unfortunately deleting or reverting the file is not working

How to do the reset in version control in intellij such that my custom branch points to the state before the .exe file is committed ( before my first commit) and cherry picking the later commits as these have the changes?

Comment: What do you mean by "*deleting or reverting the file is not working*"?

Comment: Deleting .exe file or reverting back is not deleting .exe file

Answer (score 0):

You can  [edit your history with an interactive rebase](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/edit-project-history.html#interactive-rebase).

Follow the instructions and pick "Stop to Edit" on the offending commit. Make your changes and "amend" them. Then "Continue rebase". Git will rewrite the rest of the commits on top of your new commit.

Note that Git never rewrites a commit, it replaces it with a new one with a new commit ID. All the commits it writes on top of that will have different commit IDs. If you've already shared your work, you'll have to [Force Push](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/commit-and-push-changes.html#force-push) your changes to overwrite what you had pushed before.